# osTicket email setup on LAN

Tags: email, osticket

I have setup OSTicket on a local machine. Now I am looking to configure email using their email settings. I have the email created, additionally I have also included the email credentials on the osTicket admin panel.

I am encountering the following error.

> Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server
>   (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send
>   as this sender)]

Comment: I have configured osTicket on using XAMPP on Windows 7.

Comment: From the XAMPPThe SMTP service on XAMPP is disabled. I am looking to enable SMTP but in vain.